# Save and Unsave feature

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement Save and Unsave feature in my app.
I am so close to getting it right but few problems.

1st  - I have been able to implement on click listeners to the save and unsave an item. using this

```
boolean saved_status = uploadList.get(position).getSaved_status();

holder.save_image_section.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(saved_status){
                Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_unfilled_24dp).dontTransform().into(holder.save_icon);
                uploadList.get(position).setSaved_status(false);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                unSaveImage(position, holder);
            }
            else {
                Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.ic_bookmark_filled_24dp).dontTransform().into(holder.save_icon);
                uploadList.get(position).setSaved_status(true);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                saveImage(position, holder);
            }
        }
    });
```

This works as expected...when a user clicks save, drawable changes, and image is saved succesfully in the database. same with unsave.

Problem

When user exit the app...the state of saved/unsaved items not getting stored

I know I have to check the state of items from db making network calls to get the right drawable to display...

I did that but there comes a delay in displaying the drawables especially in poor networks leading to poor UX and it messes the click listeners as saved images takes few seconds to change drawable due to network calls etc.

I have a database that stores the saved image id and the user who saved the image.

I tried this again - using volley i did this and called the method in onBindViewHolder in my adapter

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
      try {
         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
         String success = jsonObject.getString("success");

         //if the current image has been saved by the current logged in user
         if(success.equals("1")){
         //I could set drawable here but there is a delay in displaying drawable
         uploadList.get(position).setSaved_status(true);
         }
         else {
           uploadList.get(position).setSaved_status(false);
              }
         }
```

It doesnt work as it returns false for saved status even after setting it.

How do I get the state of saved items without using network calls from the database to display the drawables please??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get saved status from the activity or fragment holding the recyclerview.
2. Set saved status in the request eg

   ```
   upload.setSaved_status(saved_boolen);
   ```
3. On your adapter OnBindViewHolder, check saved status

   ```
   boolean saved_status = uploadList.get(position).getSaved_status();

   if(saved_status){
     //display saved image here
   }
   else{
     //dispaly unsaved image here
   }
   ```
4. You can then use your set Onclick for them as you already did